# Error occurred during initialization of VM macosx

Tags: macos, java-7

I see a few question with this title already.
I have checked it, if it has a solution for me, but not.

I had a java 1.6 installed the 1.7 in .bash_profile I hade an export with JAVA_HOME poiting to 1.6. I have removed and I have removed all Java / sdk related stuff, and I think I have removed from osx something too, what I shouldn't :)

I have installed the 64 bit version of the 1.7.0_13, now it isn't at the bin folder in the PATH, so if I navigate there and doubleclick on Java it will have this output:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_13.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java ; exit;
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:542)
    at java.lang.System.initProperties(Native Method)
    at java.lang.System.initializeSystemClass(System.java:1115)

logout
```

Great, what is not finding? How to solve it? I can't launch any java based program now.

OSX version 10.8.2

[image]

No effect that button if  I press it!

PS
Appengine needs 1.7 to let me login from Eclipse, not enough the 1.6 otherwise is an error message with invalid request.

UPDATE based on comment:

```
otool -L /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_13.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_13.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 17.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 55110.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 41.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.5)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 635.19.0)
```

Comment: What happens when you type `otool -L /path/to/java7`?  Does it load the Java 7 dynamic libraries?

Comment: idk, everything has a "compatibility version " does it load or it is nagging about compatibility?

Comment: it was a folder Java at /System/Library/Frameworks , which I have deleted, should I put back an empty folder? and somewhere it was a JavaVM.framework folder

Comment: Sorry, you **removed** `/System/Library/Frameworks`???

Comment: just an entry from there: the java.framework :D

Comment: @trojanfoe  put an answer with: "put back the /System/library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework entry what have you deleted" to be accepted

Comment: OK done.  Not much of an answer though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put back the `/System/Library/Frameworks/` entry that you have deleted :)

Comment: thanks for help! this solved my case, couldn't find this problem in other poststs