# Android Studio - Gradle - Error occurred during initialization of VM

Tags: android, jvm, java-8, android-gradle-plugin, apk

I'm trying to generate an APK file for a simple Java program with Android Studio on Mac OS 10.9.5 (iMac 2009) and I get the following error message when compiling :

```
08:49:25.337 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: FAILED
08:49:25.337 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_66.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with exit value 1 (state: FAILED)
08:49:25.338 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:459)
    at java.lang.System.initProperties(Native Method)
    at java.lang.System.initializeSystemClass(System.java:1166)
```

I checked many posts on the internet and it didn't help.

My JAVA_HOME is set to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_66.jdk/Contents/Home

Is there something wrong with my JDK installation ? Or with Gradle ?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Pierre

UPDATE based on comment :

```
otool -L /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_66.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_66.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 19.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 55179.0.2)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 45.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.5)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 744.1.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 945.11.0)
```

and I confirm that /System/Library/Frameworks folder exists with all subfolders.

Comment: How much RAM do you have in mac machine?

Comment: 8 GB (and I do not reach the capacity)

Comment: check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675875/error-occurred-during-initialization-of-vm-macosx

Comment: I updated the question with otool output. I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: Rebooting the mac solved the issue. Seems to be related to available memory...

Comment: Great! Happy working :-)